# HTML5 Drag and drop not working in chrome 32

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

If I drag and drop a file in latest chrome stable (v32) `webkitGetAsEntry` returns null. i.e. the entry will be null in the following code:

```
var entry = item.webkitGetAsEntry();
```

However if I click and select files they come through just fine.

Q: where can I get documentation for `webkitGetAsEntry`

Answer (score 2):

Apparently I was on the beta channel for chrome. Uninstalling and reinstalling chrome brought me back to the stable channel (v31 at the moment) which does not have this bug.

Comment: Unfortunately Chrome 32 has now been released and appears to still have the same problem. Does anybody have a solution? I can't find any good references to this issue anywhere. Perhaps it's just a bug that hasn't yet been noticed by / reported to Google?

Comment: That's what I found, they are working on it... But they released it because it was working in Gmail! https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=332579 It's not working in moxiecode plupload.

Comment: Actually I take back my comment... For me the problem only exists for items where I wasn't checking item.kind=='file'... Now that I'm ignoring all other items, I have no problem. For items where kind=='file', webkitGetAsEntry() as always.

Answer (score 0):

What? That trouble was in the DEV channel on november 14, and now it is on the STABLE channel?

All our drag-drop are now unusable using the plupload html5 upload module...

(edit) Chrome team is working on it... https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=332579

Comment: XUbuntu 13.04 / Chrome 35.0.1883.0 dev aura 
The issue still here, dnd file doesn't work